# Removing two elements from array using Notepad ++ and regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have along list of strings which looks like

```
[47,19,148,42,50]
[52,16,135,34,57],[54,16,140,36,59]
[54,16,140,32,57],[56,16,145,34,59]
...
```

I need to remove two last elements from each array to looks like

```
[47,19,148]
[52,16,135],[54,16,140]
[54,16,140],[56,16,145]
...
```

How to achieve this in Notepad++ and regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(,\d+){2}(?=\])
```

it looks for 2 lots of `,` followed by some digits, with both groups followed by a `]` (asserted using a positive lookahead so it is not captured). You can then replace that with an empty string. If there may be spaces in the data, you can make the regex work with them by adding `\s*` as needed:

```
(,\s*\d+\s*){2}(?=\])
```

[Demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pV9MaA/1)